# T-SQL: Combine rows to one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have the following table:

```
number  word
======  ====
1       AAA
2       BBB
2       CCCC
4       CCCC
4       BBB
4       AAA
```

Now I want to create a new table, where a "number" only occurs in one row. The corresponding values in "word" should be converted to comma sepeareted string.

The result table:

```
number  word
======  ====
1       AAA
2       BBB,CCCC
4       CCCCC,BBB,AAA
```

How can this solved with T-SQL? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Google:  "SQL Server aggregate string concatenation".

Comment: http://codecorner.galanter.net/2009/06/25/t-sql-string-aggregate-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started so I may as well post mine too...

```
CREATE TABLE #test
(
    ID tinyint
    ,Word varchar(20)
);
INSERT INTO #test
VALUES
(1,'aaa')
,(1,'bbb')
,(2,'abc')
,(2,'def')
,(2,'ghi')
,(3,'zzz');

SELECT DISTINCT
a.ID
,STUFF((
    SELECT
        ',' + b.Word
    FROM #test b
    WHERE a.ID = b.ID 
    FOR XML PATH('')
),1,1,'') AS [Contains]
FROM #test a
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `FOR XML`  Here is a demo of how it works [SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0836c/6)

Comment: Please do not post "link only" answers. Linked content can disappear. Post actual code.